# WPF Resources: Explicit localization of individual controls

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

Is it possible to explicitly control the culture of controls in order to set which resources (.resx)/culture to retrieve its values from?

Let's say that the global application culture to be "en-US" but I want some controls to be in "sv-SE". In my project I have a `resource.resx` and a `resource.sv-se.resx` file. It works well to switch culture/language for the entire application, but I can't figure out how to control this on a per-control level. I would have hoped that setting `Language="sv-SE"` would have sufficed, but the TextBlock is still taking its value from the English resourses file.

```
<Windows 
   xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Localization"
   ...
   >


   <TextBlock x:Name="TextInEnglish" Text="{x:Static resx:Resources.MyText}" />

   <TextBlock x:Name="TextInSwedish" Language="sv-SE" Text="{x:Static resx:Resources.MyText}" />
   ...
```

How would I go about to do this?

Comment: 2 Ideas: 1) use a value converter and a multibinding on language and text. 2), ignore the language property and create an attached property for language and text or loca id, which listens on changes and updates the text( or another property ) accordingly. But i guess there are much better ways to solve this.

Comment: @dowhilefor: Thanks for your input. I actually started off with an valueconverter but I didn't like it in the end. It got a bit messy. The 2nd idea sounds interesting but I think I would need to see in code to fully understand it, I think. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ResourceManager` class doesn't take the `Language` property into account, it uses only the [`CurrentUICulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx). But you could create a markup extension where you can specify the culture:

```
public class LocalizedResourceExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    [ConstructorArgument("resourceKey")]
    public string ResourceKey { get; set; }

    public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }

    public LocalizedResourceExtension()
    {
    }

    public LocalizedResourceExtension(string resourceKey)
    {
        this.ResourceKey = resourceKey;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ResourceKey))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ResourceKey must be set");

        return Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(
            ResourceKey, 
            Culture ?? CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
    }
}
```

You can use it in your code like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextInEnglish" Text="{loc:LocalizedResource MyText}" />

<TextBlock x:Name="TextInSwedish" Text="{loc:LocalizedResource MyText, Culture=sv-SE}"/>
```

Comment: +1 aswell, i like this idea. Perfect solution for a custom markup extension.